# Visual Studio 2010: Keyboard Shortcut to "Override Method" in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

In Visual Studio 2010, what is the keyboard shortcut to drop-down a list of C# virtual methods, and clicking them will generate an "override method" code?

In IntelliJ IDEA, that feature's shortcut is CTRL+Shift+O.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

If you type `override`<kbd>space</kbd>, or just `ov`<kbd>tab</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> you will get this list. Select the one you want <kbd>tab</kbd> and it will generate the full `override` signature and place you in the body (the caret will be placed immediately before the `base.blah(...)` call it generates).

Comment: I wish there was a direct shortcut like in IDEA, but this will do. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Generally intellisense will automatically list after you've typed (or used intellisense to complete) `override`.

Typing a space after the "e" of `override` will get the list again.